# how to export report as pdf from mysql to android app

Tags: android, mysql, pdf

1. i want to export pdf file which contains data from mysql database ...

i can successfully fetch data from database to recyclerview , i want to export this recyclerview data as PDF...
Please sugest any solution/logic that can help me....
is it possible to use **Google REST API**
https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started

this is how i fetch the json...

private void showJSONExp(String response) {

```
    try {    JSONArray a = new JSONArray(response);
        l.clear();
        total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<a.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject collegeData = a.getJSONObject(i);
            id1 = collegeData.getString("id");
            amount1 = collegeData.getString("amount");
            total += Integer.parseInt(amount1);
            description1 = collegeData.getString("description");
            date1 = collegeData.getString("date");
            emM = new ExpModel(id1, Integer.parseInt(amount1), description1, date1);
            l.add(emM);
            RADate.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+total, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        totalExp.setText(String.valueOf(total));


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: you can create pdf using iText lib see this : http://androidbeginner.blogspot.in/2012/05/creating-pdf-in-android-with-help-of.html

Comment: i already created pdf from iText lib but i want to export data from database.....how can i do that....????????